# How to get the unique Year value (using Group By) from a table with multiple date values using SQL query in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table with Holidays(Given below). How can get the unique values like 2018,2019,2020 using a sql query.

```
Date-Holiday    Memo
1/1/2018    New Year's Day
1/2/2018    Bank Holiday
1/3/2018    Bank Holiday
1/1/2019    New Year's Day
1/2/2019    Bank Holiday
1/3/2019    Bank Holiday
12/31/2019  Bank Holiday
1/1/2020    New Year's Day
1/2/2020    Bank Holiday
1/3/2020    Bank Holiday
```

Tried

```
SELECT Year([00_Holiday].[Date-Holiday]) AS ["HYear"] FROM 00_Holiday;
```

It is returning multiple values.

Tried using

```
SELECT Year([00_Holiday].[Date-Holiday]) AS ["HYear"] FROM 00_Holiday
group by [00_Holiday].[Date-Holiday];
```

but same result..

Comment: Doesn't make any sence but got required output using SELECT Year([00_Holiday].[Date-Holiday]) AS ["HYear"] FROM 00_Holiday
group by (Year([00_Holiday].[Date-Holiday]) ); Is this realiable query?

Comment: That's how GROUP BY works. If you list <Date-Holiday> column in the GROUP BY clause, you are essentially requesting that duplicate records be excluded from the result set. That gives the same effect as SELECT DISTINCT which also eliminates duplicate rows from the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Distinct* and the correct syntax:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT Year([Date-Holiday]) AS [HYear] FROM [00_Holiday];"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @t table (Holiday varchar(50),memo varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('1/1/2018','New Years Day')
insert into @t values ('1/1/2018','Bank Holiday')
insert into @t values ('1/1/2019','New Years Day')


select t.Holiday,t.memo from
( select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by right(holiday,4) order by memo ) rn,holiday,memo from @t
) t
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (DateHoliday DATE, Memo VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES 
('1/1/2018','a'),
('1/2/2018','b'),
('1/3/2018','c'),
('1/2/2019','d'),
('1/3/2019','e')

-- Method 1:-

SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DateHoliday) AS [Year] 
FROM #temp

-- Method 2

SELECT [Year] 
FROM #temp
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(YEAR(DateHoliday))) AS Y([Year])
GROUP BY [Year]
```

The result is as below,

```
Year
2018
2019
```

Comment: Method 1 uses DISTINCT, but it has drawback that it can increase load on the query engine
Method 2 uses Group By which is more reliable